# Is there a Ruby gem to use the Google Images API?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I need to talk with the Google Images API on my Rails Application. Is there a Ruby gem to do this? I found an old gem that used the deprecated API.

Comment: Is this the Gem you found: http://rubygems.org/gems/google_image_api

Answer (score 8):

There is a gem called `google_custom_search_api` that uses the newer google custom search API:
https://github.com/wiseleyb/google_custom_search_api

You can limit this to image search by specifying `image` for the `searchType` parameter, like so:

```
 results = GoogleCustomSearchApi.search("poker", {"searchType" => "image"})
```

Comment: lol - i totally forgot about this project and was looking for a google-image api - thanks for pointing me back to my project :)

Answer (score 1):

Also there is another gem called **image_suckr** - https://github.com/maurimiranda/image_suckr also you can do somthing similar directly in Google Image Search API

> suckr = ImageSuckr::GoogleSuckr.new
>   suckr.get_image_url({"q" => "car"})

Comment: Seems to be no longer working due to Google API changes

Answer (score 1):

You can use SerpApi [gem](https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-ruby) to scrape Google Images results. You'll have to set `tbm` parameter set as `ishch`.

For example, to fetch dolphins images:

```
require 'google_search_results' 

params = {
  q: "Dolphins",
  location: "Austin, Texas, United States",
  hl: "en",
  gl: "us",
  google_domain: "google.com",
  tbm: "isch",
}

query = GoogleSearchResults.new(params)
hash_results = query.get_hash
```

More information about the Google Images API: https://serpapi.com/images-results